# Convert a complex SQL query to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, geospatial

I run out of ideas. I googled now more then one day and I still can't find any useful answer to my question.

What I did until now, I tried to use raw SQL but without luck.

```
locations = db.session.query(Location, select([text('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians("53.6209798282177") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians("13.96948162900808") ) + sin( radians("53.6209798282177") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )')]).label('distance')).having('distance' < 25).all()
```

When using this raw SQL query I get zero results returned, but when running the same query in `mysql` it returns correct results.

Further more I figured out, that when printing the query to terminal, it does not handle the `HAVING()` clause correctly.

My query looks like this when printed:

```
SELECT location.id AS location_id, location.created_date AS location_created_date, location.zip AS location_zip, location.user_id AS location_user_id, location.lat AS location_lat, location.lng AS location_lng, location.city AS location_city 
FROM location 
HAVING false = 1
```

**How do I convert this SQL query to SQLAlchemy**

```
SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(53.6209798282177) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(11.96948162900808) ) + sin( radians(53.6209798282177) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM location HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

My table looks like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(50)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| created_date | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| zip          | varchar(5)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| user_id      | varchar(50)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lat          | decimal(15,13) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lng          | decimal(15,13) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city         | text           | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `HAVING` is handled correctly, but you're passing it the wrong expression. It seems that you're using Python 2, since the relational comparison between a string and an integer

```
'distance' < 25
```

does not raise an exception, but evaluates to `False` instead. In other words your query is equal to

```
locations = db.session.query(...).having(False).all()
```

which explains why you get zero results: all rows are explicitly filtered out by the HAVING clause, as seen in the printed version:

```sql
...
HAVING false = 1  -- remove all rows
```

A solution is to use a suitable construct, such as [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column), to produce the expression:

```
locations = db.session.query(...).having(column('distance') < 25).all()
```

You shouldn't wrap the complex select list item expression in a [`select()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select), which represents a SELECT statement. Either label the `text()` as is:

```
text('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians("53.6209798282177") ) * '
     'cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians("13.96948162900808") ) + '
     'sin( radians("53.6209798282177") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) '
     'AS distance')
```

or build the expression using the model:

```
(6371 *
 func.acos(func.cos(func.radians(53.6209798282177)) *
           func.cos(func.radians(Location.lat)) *
           func.cos(func.radians(Location.lng) - func.radians(13.96948162900808)) +
           func.sin(func.radians(53.6209798282177)) *
           func.sin(func.radians(Location.lat)))).label('distance')
```

You could improve the readability of your query construction by making a function for the [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), and with a little bit of work you could implement a [hybrid method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method) on `Location`:

```
import math

def gc_distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, math=math):
    ang = math.acos(math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) *
                    math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) *
                    math.cos(math.radians(lng2) -
                             math.radians(lng1)) +
                    math.sin(math.radians(lat1)) *
                    math.sin(math.radians(lat2)))

    return 6371 * ang

class Location(db.Model):
    ...
    @hybrid_method
    def distance(self, lat, lng):
        return gc_distance(lat, lng, self.lat, self.lng)

    @distance.expression
    def distance(cls, lat, lng):
        return gc_distance(lat, lng, cls.lat, cls.lng, math=func)

locations = db.session.query(
        Location,
        Location.distance(53.6209798282177,
                          13.96948162900808).label('distance')).\
    having(column('distance') < 25).\
    order_by('distance').\
    all()
```

---

Note that the way you use HAVING to eliminate non-group rows is not portable. For example in Postgresql the presence of [HAVING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING) turns a query in to a grouped query, even without a GROUP BY clause. You could use a subquery instead:

```
stmt = db.session.query(
        Location,
        Location.distance(53.6209798282177,
                          13.96948162900808).label('distance')).\
    subquery()

location_alias = db.aliased(Location, stmt)

locations = db.session.query(location_alias).\
    filter(stmt.c.distance < 25).\
    order_by(stmt.c.distance).\
    all()
```