# SQL query to SQLAlchemy (flask-sqlalchemy) with subqueries

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this SQL query I want to convert to SLQAlchemy (flask-sqlalchemy)
The query use pagination

SQL query

```
queryPostgres = db.text("""
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () as RowCount
    FROM (
        SELECT * ,
            ( 3958.75 *
            acos(sin(:lat1 / 57.2958) * sin( cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) +
                 cos(:lat1 / 57.2958) * cos( cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) *
                 cos( cast(longitude as double precision) / 57.2958 - :lon1/57.2958)))
            as distanceInMiles
        FROM "job" ) zc
    WHERE zc.distanceInMiles < :dst
    ORDER BY zc.distanceInMiles
    LIMIT :per_page
    OFFSET :offset
""")
```

To SQLALchemy as

```
 @classmethod
    def getJobsWithinXMiles2(cls, lat1: str, lon1: str, dst: str):

        return cls.query.filter(
            (3958.75 *
                acos(sin(lat1 / 57.2958) * sin(latitude / 57.2958) +
                cos(lat1 / 57.2958) * cos(latitude / 57.2958) *
                cos(longitude / 57.2958 - lon1/57.2958))) as distanceInMiles)  \
            .where(distanceInMiles < dst) \
            .order_by(distanceInMiles) \
            .paginate(page=_page, per_page=_per_page)
```

But I'm getting an error in the SQLAlchemy

This is the mode for clarification

```
class Job(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "job"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    zipCode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    longitude = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    narrative = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    companyLogo = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    companyName = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    companyURL = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

But I do not manage to make it work.
Could some one help please in convert this sql query to SQLAlchemy?

Comment: This model and methods are used in flask-sqlalchemy ORM.Some moderator proposed  I remove the flask-sqlalchmey and when I did not , immediately degraded the question. Vengeance in Stackoverflow , lol

Comment: Yes the same question with exactly the same problem  was already asked as we can see below in the Answer .For any one interested follow the response below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question was here:

[Convert a complex SQL query to SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014687/convert-a-complex-sql-query-to-sqlalchemy)

And was correctly answered by who ? Well the same guy who has saved me more than one time  [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4)

Thank you so much Ilja for your help and support